# GWT OAuth2 modern library

Tags: java, gwt, oauth-2.0

Is there any OAuth library for GWT that not in alpha stage?

I can find https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api/gwt-oauth2/0.2 this, but it's alpha version (last update in 2011). Is it so bad in GWT world that there is no client-side library for OAuth? Or there is some other reason for that?